# How do I update the state of a disable bootstrap toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a read only bootstrap toggle that is supposed to reflect the state of a system (enabled/disabled). It's supposed to update every time the following getCall() is run. When I read the console, the var data will be true but the toggle won't reflect it. I've tried changing the value of a disabled toggle but that doesn't work. What's the proper way to do this?

```
function getCall(toggle_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function(data) {
            console.log("should be", data)
            $(toggle_id).bootstrapToggle("enable");
            $(toggle_id).bootstrapToggle("on", data);
            $(toggle_id).bootstrapToggle("disable");
            $(toggle_id).bootstrapToggle();
    }).fail(function(data,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Comment: you are calling enable and disable in the success callback why?

Comment: The bootstrapToggle("on", data) function won't work if the toggle is left disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following line and it worked:

from

```
$(toggle_id).bootstrapToggle("on", data);
```

to

```
data ? $(toggle_id).bootstrapToggle("on"): $(toggle_id).bootstrapToggle("off");
```